# How to set default bluetooth adapter name in android source code?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have checked this one:
Visit [Can anybody tell me ,how to custom the local Bluetooth device name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155475/can-anybody-tell-me-how-to-custom-the-local-bluetooth-device-name)

I think that changing name in **/system/etc/bluetooth/*main.conf*** can not work on **Android 4.2.2**, but it works fine in **4.1**.

Does anyone have solution for this?

I can not find other config for changing bt default name~

Please give some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If using bluez,

/usr/sbin/hciconfig hci0 name NEW_NAME

Comment: Hi ashish,

Thanks for answering~

if I use android source project, where can I find the config file to 

modify the bluetooth adapter name in Bluez version?

Thank you

Comment: @vick753 : 4.2.2 does not have Bluez, its replaced by Broadcom stack, not sure of the flow, your change in main.conf was correct

Comment: ＠ashish: You're right. 4.2.2 is Bluedroid. And main.conf is not work.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you try "\device\\\bluetooth\bdroid_buildcfg.h" 
 # define BTM_DEF_LOCAL_NAME "New-default name"